# AutoMapper (non-static) configuration with Map method in BeforeMap/AfterMap

Tags: automapper

In the latest and recommended AutoMapper version (4.2.1) the static model has been abandoned. So in the new model a configuration might look like this:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(
        cfg =>
          {
          cfg.CreateMap<Market_DTO, IMarket>().ConstructUsingServiceLocator();
          cfg.CreateMap<MarketList_DTO, IMarketList>()
            .ConstructUsingServiceLocator()
            .BeforeMap((src, dest) => src.Markets.ForEach(x =>  dest.Add(Mapper.Map<Market_DTO, IMarket>(x))));
          cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(Type => Root.Service.GetInstance(Type));
      });
```

In run-time, this will produce an exception that the Map from Market_DTO to IMarket (within the BeforeMap statement) is a "Missing type map configuration", presumably because I'm using the static Mapper.Map method. But how else can you define a Map within the configuration using a BeforeMap/AfterMap statement ?

Comment: Why are you mapping `Markets` yourself?  If you've already told Automapper how to map type `T1` to `T2`, it will [automatically handle](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Lists-and-arrays) mapping `IEnumerable<T1>` to `IEnumerable<T2>`.

Comment: Because I'm mapping from an explicit list to an inherited list (and perform some initialization in the dest.Add method), but if you have a better idea, I'm all ears.

Comment: So what happens if you eliminate the BeforeMap -- does it generate an error?  You might want to include your source and destination types.  That will help us see the type of mappings you need defined.

Comment: If I remove the BeforeMap, no list items get mapped. The source type  MarketList_DTO contains an IList<Market_DTO> property that I want to map to the destination: class MarketList : List<IMarket>. I've tried to use the following maps:

Comment: If I remove the BeforeMap, no list items get mapped. The source type  MarketList_DTO contains an IList<Market_DTO> property (named Markets) that I want to map to the destination: class MarketList : List<IMarket>. I've tried to use the following maps:        Mapper.CreateMap<List<IMarket>, IList<Market_DTO>>();
Mapper.CreateMap<IList<Market_DTO>, List<IMarket>>();  They will, however, return the same result: no map.

Answer (score 3):

For people that are still looking for the answer:

You can declare an IMapper outside of the MapperConfiguration, use this as a closure in the Before/AfterMap, and create it afterwards. Example:

```cs
IMapper mapper = null;

var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Model.Entities.Invoice, Invoice>()
        .AfterMap((src, dest) =>
        {
            dest.Supplier = mapper.Map<InvoiceSupplier>(src);
        });
});

mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```